# How to get these divs side-by-side on same line?

Tags: css

How do I override CSS that makes divs stack on top of each other and run full-width, to instead make the divs run left to right?

Specifically, how do I modify mine, 3 x `.notion-callout` or a child, at the bottom of this card, which run left to right, to ensure that they run side-by-side each other?

[image]

The objective is to have the grey boxes be only about as wide as the icons contained within, rather than stretch full-width, starting from the left.

(1) One thing I have done is to apply `visibility: hidden` to some anchor text in those boxes (I'm not in a position to alter the mark-up, only the CSS and CSS overrides).
(2) I have also poured over many similar Stackoverflow threads.
(3) I have tried applying a range of display values, ie. `inline`, `inline-block`, but can't get the box width to constrain.

```css
/*I believe this is the relevant CSS. There is also an ultimate parent class with `display: flex`.*/

.notion-root.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
.notion-root {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.notion-callout {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.notion-callout {
  position: relative !important;
}

.notion-callout__icon {
  width: 1.8em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  padding: 1.2px;
}

.notion-callout__content {
  margin-left: 8px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.notion-semantic-string {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.notion-semantic-string {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.notion-semantic-string .link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-text-default-light);
  opacity: .7;
  -moz-transition: border-color .1s ease-in, opacity .1s ease-in;
  transition: border-color .1s ease-in, opacity .1s ease-in;
}

.notion-callout a {
  padding: 0 0 2px 50px !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  display: flex !important;
  border: none !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<article id="block-44da810a1ed446bf9bf9c9ce058b1702" class="notion-root full-width">
  <h3 id="block-d55821810b9b4f199d3befb349f1b29e" class="notion-heading">
    <span class="notion-heading__anchor" id="d55821810b9b4f199d3befb349f1b29e"></span
        ><span class="notion-semantic-string"><span>Multiverse analyst</span></span>
  </h3>
  <div id="block-b26901cad4bf4def825f154ebe30e0c7" class="notion-text">
    <p class="notion-text__content">
      <span class="notion-semantic-string"><span
              >Lorem ipsum dolor ex magna. Interdum malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
              amet et faucibus. Pellentesque et venenatis.</span
            ></span
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="block-d6140ff909d34f99833ae73922f1a2e1" class="notion-text">
        <p class="notion-text__content">
          <span class="notion-semantic-string"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="block-974b3353883a4998b6ca59807914ceb9" class="notion-callout bg-gray-light border">
    <div class="notion-callout__icon">
      <div style="
              overflow: hidden;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              width: 24px;
              height: 24px;
            ">
        <img alt="icon" src="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F755f0732-a73d-4410-b418-ff2f269a66b0.png&amp;w=640&amp;q=100" decoding="async" class="notion-icon" style="
                visibility: visible;
                position: absolute;
                inset: 0px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0px;
                border: medium none;
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 0px;
                height: 0px;
                min-width: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
              " srcset="
                /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F755f0732-a73d-4410-b418-ff2f269a66b0.png&amp;w=640&amp;q=100 1x
              " />
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="notion-callout__content">
      <span class="notion-semantic-string"><span
              ><a
                href="http://www.notionhq.com"
                class="notion-link link"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >PollardsProgress</a
              ></span
            ></span
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div
        id="block-99956269608948c2a97ac5603368a892"
        class="notion-callout bg-gray-light border"
      >
        <div class="notion-callout__icon">
          <div
            style="
              overflow: hidden;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              width: 24px;
              height: 24px;
            "
          >
            <img
              alt="icon"
              src="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F3f605f41-8b78-4e86-b128-69e547cb34a3.png&amp;w=640&amp;q=100"
              decoding="async"
              class="notion-icon"
              style="
                visibility: visible;
                position: absolute;
                inset: 0px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0px;
                border: medium none;
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 0px;
                height: 0px;
                min-width: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
              "
              srcset="
                /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2F3f605f41-8b78-4e86-b128-69e547cb34a3.png&amp;w=640&amp;q=100 1x
              "
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="notion-callout__content">
          <span class="notion-semantic-string"
            ><span
              ><a
                href="http://www.notionhq.com"
                class="notion-link link"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >CaycePollard</a
              ></span
            ></span
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div
        id="block-22e0c2a2e50a409ba6606503372bfa41"
        class="notion-callout bg-gray-light border"
      >
        <div class="notion-callout__icon">
          <div
            style="
              overflow: hidden;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              width: 24px;
              height: 24px;
            "
          >
            <img
              alt="icon"
              src="/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2Fee17734e-3566-4b32-b1e1-952dabc764bf.png&amp;w=640&amp;q=100"
              decoding="async"
              class="notion-icon"
              style="
                visibility: visible;
                position: absolute;
                inset: 0px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0px;
                border: medium none;
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 0px;
                height: 0px;
                min-width: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
              "
              srcset="
                /_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.super.so%2Fasset%2Fdemo.notionware.shop%2Fee17734e-3566-4b32-b1e1-952dabc764bf.png&amp;w=640&amp;q=100 1x
              "
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="notion-callout__content">
          <span class="notion-semantic-string"
            ><span
              ><a
                href="http://www.medium.com"
                class="notion-link link"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >Cayce's Musings</a
              ></span
            ></span
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="block-06ddcfa82b06404c87c3329408b97d7d" class="notion-text">
        <p class="notion-text__content">
          <span class="notion-semantic-string"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Maybe `.notion-callout{ display: inline-flex' }`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There is a typo above, try `.notion-callout{ display: inline-flex; }` or `.notion-callout{ display: inline-flex !important; }`. If that doesn't work, than you haven't posted all the relevant styles involved.

Comment: I think a powerful `display: flex` is set at `<article>` (whose CSS I have now added above) because, when I `unset` that `display`, everything goes side-by-side. The trouble is, the grey boxes alone are not contained in their own `div`, so ALL `div`s go side-by-side, including the content above. That's why I hoped a solution could be found at `div.notion-callout` or beneath.

Answer (score 0):

As written above you can use CSS flex layout or you can also build a [CSS grid layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

```css
/*I believe this is the relevant CSS. There is also an ultimate parent class with `display: flex`.*/

.notion-root{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
.notion-heading{
  grid-column: 1 /span 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.notion-text{
  grid-column: 1 /span 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.notion-callout {
  grid-row: 3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.notion-callout__icon {
  width: 1.8em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  padding: 1.2px;
}

.notion-callout__content {
  margin-left: 8px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.notion-semantic-string {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.notion-semantic-string {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.notion-semantic-string .link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-text-default-light);
  opacity: .7;
  -moz-transition: border-color .1s ease-in, opacity .1s ease-in;
  transition: border-color .1s ease-in, opacity .1s ease-in;
}

.notion-callout a {
  padding: 0 0 2px 50px !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  display: flex !important;
  border: none !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<article id="block-44da810a1ed446bf9bf9c9ce058b1702" class="notion-root full-width">
  <h3 id="block-d55821810b9b4f199d3befb349f1b29e" class="notion-heading">
    <span class="notion-heading__anchor" id="d55821810b9b4f199d3befb349f1b29e"></span
        ><span class="notion-semantic-string"><span>Multiverse analyst</span></span>
  </h3>
  <div id="block-b26901cad4bf4def825f154ebe30e0c7" class="notion-text">
    <p class="notion-text__content">
      <span class="notion-semantic-string"><span
              >Lorem ipsum dolor ex magna. Interdum malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
              amet et faucibus. Pellentesque et venenatis.</span
            ></span
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="block-d6140ff909d34f99833ae73922f1a2e1" class="notion-text">
        <p class="notion-text__content">
          <span class="notion-semantic-string"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="block-974b3353883a4998b6ca59807914ceb9" class="notion-callout bg-gray-light border">
    <div class="notion-callout__icon">
      <div style="
              overflow: hidden;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              width: 24px;
              height: 24px;
            ">
        <img alt="icon" src="https://picsum.photos/200" decoding="async" class="notion-icon" style="
                visibility: visible;
                position: absolute;
                inset: 0px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0px;
                border: medium none;
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 0px;
                height: 0px;
                min-width: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
              " srcset="
                https://picsum.photos/200
              " />
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="notion-callout__content">
      <span class="notion-semantic-string"><span
              ><a
                href="http://www.notionhq.com"
                class="notion-link link"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >PollardsProgress</a
              ></span
            ></span
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div
        id="block-99956269608948c2a97ac5603368a892"
        class="notion-callout bg-gray-light border"
      >
        <div class="notion-callout__icon">
          <div
            style="
              overflow: hidden;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              width: 24px;
              height: 24px;
            "
          >
            <img
              alt="icon"
              src="https://picsum.photos/200"
              decoding="async"
              class="notion-icon"
              style="
                visibility: visible;
                position: absolute;
                inset: 0px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0px;
                border: medium none;
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 0px;
                height: 0px;
                min-width: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
              "
              srcset="
                https://picsum.photos/200
              "
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="notion-callout__content">
          <span class="notion-semantic-string"
            ><span
              ><a
                href="http://www.notionhq.com"
                class="notion-link link"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >CaycePollard</a
              ></span
            ></span
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div
        id="block-22e0c2a2e50a409ba6606503372bfa41"
        class="notion-callout bg-gray-light border"
      >
        <div class="notion-callout__icon">
          <div
            style="
              overflow: hidden;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              display: inline-block;
              position: relative;
              width: 24px;
              height: 24px;
            "
          >
            <img
              alt="icon"
              src="https://picsum.photos/200"
              decoding="async"
              class="notion-icon"
              style="
                visibility: visible;
                position: absolute;
                inset: 0px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0px;
                border: medium none;
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 0px;
                height: 0px;
                min-width: 100%;
                max-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
              "
              srcset="
                https://picsum.photos/200
              "
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="notion-callout__content">
          <span class="notion-semantic-string"
            ><span
              ><a
                href="http://www.medium.com"
                class="notion-link link"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >Cayce's Musings</a
              ></span
            ></span
          >
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="block-06ddcfa82b06404c87c3329408b97d7d" class="notion-text">
        <p class="notion-text__content">
          <span class="notion-semantic-string"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</article>
```